# Text box validation using regular expression in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a textbox and have to use the regular expressions in asp.net

My text should not allow the spaces in first and last place.

### Output should be:

Valid:
`[India Bangalore]`

Not valid:
`[ India Bangalore ]`

i.e : user can enter the spaces in between the words but not in first position and last position.

If you have solution in JavaScript that is also fine.

Comment: Why not call .Trim() and don't bother the user about the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please :

```
^[^\s].*[^\s]$
```

It simply match input which:
not to start with any white space `^[^\s]` followed by any character even white spaces `.*` and not end with any white space `[^\s]$`.

Any way calling Trim() method on input string in server-side is much easy .

Answer (score 1):

Trim() should remove any trailing or leading spaces.